# Can I define the general concept of x==y = p(x) == p(y) in Idris?

Tags: idris

I want to define a type constructor which embodies the concept of using a type wrapper to define equality on a domain type `t1` by projecting onto a domain type `t2` with a function `p`.

The following specific example works, where `t1` = `ABC`, `t2` = `Nat` and `p` is the function `abc_2_nat`:

```
%default total

data ABC = A | B | C

abc_2_nat : ABC -> Nat
abc_2_nat A = 1
abc_2_nat B = 1
abc_2_nat C = 2

data Projected_abc : Type where
  Project_abc : ABC -> Projected_abc

Projected_abc_equals : Projected_abc -> Projected_abc -> Bool
Projected_abc_equals (Project_abc x) (Project_abc y) = abc_2_nat x == abc_2_nat y

Eq Projected_abc where 
  (==) = Projected_abc_equals
```

But, when I attempt to generalize as follows:

```
data Projected : t1 -> t2 -> (p: t1 -> t2) -> Type
  where Project : t1 -> Projected t1 t2 p

Projected_equals : Projected t1 t2 p -> Projected t1 t2 p -> Bool
Projected_equals (Project x) (Project y) = ?hole
```

I get this hole:

```
- + Main.hole [P]
 `--       phTy : Type
             t2 : phTy
              p : Type -> phTy
             t1 : Type
              x : t1
              y : t1
     --------------------------
      Main.hole : Bool
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't recognise that `p` is of type `t1->t2` (which is what I want).

I suspect that I'm asking too much to supply the projection function as an argument to a type constructor, and somehow have the projection function available in the scope of the definition of a function whose parameters belong to the constructed type.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

It's can be done. You `Projected` generalization is not accurate enough. You should specify types of `t1` and `t2`. Like this:

```
data Projected : (t1: Type) -> (t2: Type) -> (p: t1 -> t2) -> Type where
    Project : t1 -> Projected t1 t2 p
```

Without this Idris compiler can't guess what kind of thing are `t1` and `t2` exactly. One more note: to compare values of type `t1` by comparing projections to `t2` domain, you should be sure that you can compare values of type `t2`. Thus general projection equality looks like this:

```
projected_equals : Eq t2 => Projected t1 t2 p -> Projected t1 t2 p -> Bool
projected_equals {p} (Project x) (Project y) = p x == p y
```

And you can write `Eq` instance for it!

```
Eq t2 => Eq (Projected t1 t2 p) where
    (==) = projected_equals
```

And it also works. So if you define something like this:

```
data ABC = A | B | C

abc_2_nat : ABC -> Nat
abc_2_nat A = 1
abc_2_nat B = 1
abc_2_nat C = 2
```

You can use your `abc_2_nat` projection to implement corresponding projector:

```
abcNatProjector : ABC -> Projected ABC Nat Main.abc_2_nat
abcNatProjector abc = Project abc
```

I have to use `Main.abc_2_nat` to resolve ambiguilty because otherwise `abc_2_nat` can be any implicit type parameter. Idris has no power to guess what you want. Gladly, compiler helps me with this warning:

```
Eq.idr:13:37-46:WARNING: abc_2_nat is bound as an implicit
    Did you mean to refer to Main.abc_2_nat?
```

And now you can check in REPL that it works!

```
λΠ> abcNatProjector A == abcNatProjector B
True : Bool
λΠ> abcNatProjector A == abcNatProjector C
False : Bool
```

**Bonus addition:**

If you mark `abcNatProjector` as `implicit` function, like this:

```
implicit
abcNatProjector : ABC -> Projected ABC Nat Main.abc_2_nat
abcNatProjector abc = Project abc
```

You can define some fancy operator

```
infixr 5 ==^
(==^) : Eq t2 => Projected t1 t2 p -> Projected t1 t2 p -> Bool
(==^) = projected_equals
```

And compare values of type `ABC` with it without using `abcNatProjector` explicitly.

```
λΠ> A ==^ B
True : Bool
λΠ> A ==^ C
False : Bool
```

Comment: that fixes my problem. My basic error was to confuse types and values in the definition of the type of `Projected`. As it happened, Idris accepted my definition as valid (because in Idris types _are_ values, so putting one in place of the other isn't necessarily invalid). But when I compiled a proof hole, the types were different to what I expected. So the moral is, if you see a proof hole where the types seem strange or confusing, check that you didn't mix up types and values in some earlier definition that the hole depends on.

Comment: @PhilipDorrell Yes, another moral is: specifying types of things explicitly helps to avoid errors as earlier as possible.